# Diagnose DNS problem

Tags: ubuntu, troubleshooting, dns

Ubuntu Maverick 10.10 i386 (beta).

From my box I can ping any host outside my gateway or on local network (including my DNS server).

But I can't resolve any domain name:

`$ nslookup google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`

Please help me to diagnose this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have proper DNS servers listed in /etc/resolv.conf

Edit it as root and add these two lines-

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

This will add the Google Public DNS servers.
Try resolving domains after that.
If it doesn't work, run /etc/rc.d/network restart (or reboot your box).

Comment: It worked, thanks. Very strange: DNS worked properly this morning, I haven't changed system settings (just used some wi-fi and then connected back to my home network). Also my /etc/network/interfaces already have the line "dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8"...

Comment: I don't know about exact ubuntu design, but I know one thing- the Linux resolver library checks /etc/resolv.conf for preferred DNS servers, and you didn't have them in the file. DNS may've worked in the morning due to gateway or something else.

Comment: Funny thing. Entries in /etc/resolv.conf are cleared each time I connect to WiFi network and then switch back to the cable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because Ubuntu uses its own Network Manager to configure interfaces and protocols.
Try checking the content of `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`. Here you will find the configuration files for your interfaces.
After modification, do a `sudo service network-manager restart`